# Phonegap and jQuery Mobile Event Fires Twice at a Time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile that an event fires twice
on a `bookdetailpage(bookdetailpage.html`) in my app.When i select the checkbox an event fires and do some update to a Web Service.(`updateBooksInMybooks()` in the code)

I only want to select the checkbox and update must be done in background,Nothing more.if checkbox is checked then it should be remain as it is or if its not it should be unchecked (as normal case).

But when i tap/check on the checkbox it seems working correctly but event fires twice at a time.

1. First time (as it should) when you tap/check the checkbox.
2. Second time it fire again when i click/tap anywhere on the screen.

it's like it hangs and waits for a new click/tap on the screen,So it can fire again.

Here is the code:

```
...
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="detailpage"  data-url="detailpage.html">
<div data-role="header" id="hdrBokDetaljer" name="hdrBokDetaljer"  data-theme="c" >
      ...
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="contentBokDetaljer" name="contentBokDetaljer" >
        ...        
 <div id="detailmybooks">
   <fieldset id="mybooksGroup" data-role="controlgroup">                    
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkInMybooks" id="checkInMybooks" class="custom" />
       <label for="checkInMybooks">My books</label>    
   </fieldset>               
 </div>            
</div>

<div data-role="footer" id="ftrBokDetaljer" name="ftrBokDetaljer" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(document).delegate('#detailpage', 'pagecreate', function () {

      $('#checkInMybooks').attr("checked", detailCheckboxVar); 

   });

   $('#checkInMybooks').change(function () {

       //event.preventDefault();
       updateBooksInMybooks($('#detailbookid').html());

       return false;
   });
</script> 
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had a similar problem so I post this in hope it will help somebody. The double firing of taps and clicks went away when I properly waited on the "deviceReady" event from PhoneGap to fire. If I waited on that, taps and clicks only fired once, but if I didn't wait, then they'd fire twice. Here's how to make it work:

Add to your body tag

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

And then add some JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onBodyLoad() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   }

   function onDeviceReady() {
      $(function() {
         // Do your stuff here, binding to elements, etc
      });
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, `on('click')`.

For an example:

```
$("#btn_back_home").on('click',function(event)
{
    $.mobile.changePage( "#mobile_page_main", {reverse: true,changeHash: false});
});
```